# Is it possible in MonoTouch to determine if the user clicked on an image in a BadgeElement?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have amended the TODO list app to use a badge element instead of the boolean element as follows:

```
    protected void PopulateTable()
    {
        tasks = TaskManager.GetTasks().ToList ();
        UIImage ticked = new UIImage("checkbox_checked.png");
        UIImage unticked = UIImage.FromFile("checkbox_unchecked.png");

        Root = new RootElement("Tasky") {
            new Section() {
                from t in tasks
                select (Element) new BadgeElement(t.Completed ? ticked : unticked, (t.Name==""?"<new task>":t.Name), delegate {
                        Console.WriteLine("???");

                    })
            }
        }; 
    }
```

Is it possible to check to see if the user has clicked an icon rather than the text, and change the behaviour? Essentially I want to do this...

```
        var task = tasks[indexPath.Row];

        if(clickedIcon) {
            currentTask = task;
            task.Completed = !task.Completed;
            TaskManager.SaveTask(currentTask);
        } else {
            ShowTaskDetails(task);
        }
```

But I don't see any parameters inside IndexPath that allow me to access the column or the tapped element.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom version of the BadgeElement, and basically raise an event for the image that is separate from raising an event for the text.

Luckily for you, the whole [source code is available](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements/ElementBadge.cs), so you can just copy/paste BadgeElement, rename it, create a new unique key and modify it.